# How do I get the Beaver Team achievement?

Tags: achievements, payday-2

So me and a few friends have been trying to get this achievement but never make it.  How is it possible?  Does each member have to find a chainsaw?  If so what are the possible spawn points?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Easiest way is for everyone to bring a saw, as well as one person to bring C4, C4 one of the trees, and as soon as the C4 detonates everyone use their saw on a tree, all threes destroyed in 2 seconds. [Watch This Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PVL1yGXkxsM) and [This Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=m8-MnLcEN6E)

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  My team and I managed to get it using 4 saws and, whilst speaking on TS, timed it to all go at a marker on the in-game clock.  Reason for this is that there can be desync between the client(s) and the host, whereas the clock is fairly accurate for all.